# gogo: BundleException: An error occurred trying to read the bundle in OSGi with Equinox

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, osgi, osgi-bundle

I create OSGI bundle according to  [this](http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/develop-osgi-bundles-using-maven-bundle-plugin) tutorial, but when I try to install bundle using:

```
osgi> install file:/<path>/sample01-1.0.0.jar
```

it will show this error:

```
 Hello World...!
 osgi> install file:/sample01-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar<br>
 gogo: BundleException: An error occurred trying to read the bundle<br>
 osgi> "
```

What is the problem? This is my first OSGI bundle.

Comment: Please copy and paste the complete error message.

Comment: You are installing sample01-1.0.0 but the message talks of 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT. Make sure you didn't make a mistake, since this is likely a path problem

Comment: 1st I mention about common command to install OSGI bundle 2nd I mention about my CLI action

Answer (score 6):

For Windows:

```
osgi> install file:///d://dir1//dir2//file.jar
```

For Linux:

You must first check if the jar file is set to the appropriate access permission.

```
osgi> install file:///home//user//osgi//plugin.jar
```

Comment: Consider adding explanation on OP's problem not just 'codez that works'

Comment: Yes, it was the file path .Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs if the jar doesn't exist. Is the jar located in the root, because /sample... will search it in the root. Under windows it will similar to C:/sample....